# Azure VM with VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

This is more one for curiosity and learning.

I currently have an Azure VM (Windows 2016 and SQL 2017) which I just use for R&D. The RDP port is enabled - no big deal as there is nothing top secret.

But just to learn more about Azure I wanted to create a VPN so I can connect via that.  Googling, has left me a tad confused as how to go about this gateways, gateway subnet etc etc. I'm not sure if the articles I am reading are the right ones as whatever I try doesn't appear to work.

Does anyone know of any links that might help me start from scratch with VPN settings to connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set up a VPN type of P2S, you can make a Self-signed root certificate for free. And the steps are also simple. And you can follow the document [Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a VNet using native Azure certificate authentication: Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal). I'm glad if this can help you.

Comment: If the answer is helpful?

Comment: This guide is not complete. I've followed it up to the client side, and it made no mention of how a VM fits into the picture. My VM is still totally accessible without using a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

I found these series of Microsoft training guides to be super helpful. (you can find them via the azure portal on the overview page of a virtual network resource)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-azure-virtual-networks/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=portal
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-implement-network-monitoring/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-implement-network-security-monitoring/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/integrate-vnets-with-vnet-peering/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-a-hybrid-network-architecture/